# Cannot open source file: 'WIN32': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Getting this error building a C++ project in VS2008. Very confused what it means, why does it think WIN32 is a file?

Comment: You have anything like `#include<win32>` in your code may be?

Comment: Thou shalt not ask such questions without providing source code!

Comment: What is the type of project ? Win32 , console or MFC ? See this thread:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/99c7192f-b1d1-4df2-a952-8d99ac886ad3

Comment: You want hundreds of files? I don't know where it's from, if I did I'd know where the problem is!

Comment: @Madhur... how do you know after a project is created which was picked?

Comment: How about you look at the line number that appears next to the error, then paste that line of code in here?

Comment: @OJ there isn't one, this is the entire error message

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to **Project**-->**Properties**--**>C/C++**-->**Command line**. You most probably have a `/I""` before your `/D "WIN32"`. For some reason an empty include directive causes the /D to evaporate hence your error.

Go to **Project**-->**Properties**-->**C/C++**-->**General**-->**Additional include directories** and make sure there are no redundant chars there.

It can for example arise when the last include directory is a reference to an environement variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yup.  Post the content in the question if that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

the /I "" is most likely caused by undefined environment variables, e.g. If you have /I $(BOOSTROOT), then you will get /I "" and it will eat the next token '/D' and leaving WIN32 as a file